# how can I add inner shadow to the images in my grid?

Tags: jquery, html, css, grid

My brain hurts, I can't get this working

I'm trying to add inner shadow to these boxes so they look a bit seperate from eachother
https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6NZb.png

**http://jsfiddle.net/96d7udd7/**

I tried this one

```
img { 
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

but it only gave the logo a inner shadow instead of the images in the box

---

This is the HTML of the box's

```
    <figure class="imgbox">
        <img src="img/1.jpg" height="400px" alt="image01"/>
        <figcaption style="background: rgb(53, 25, 10)">
            <h2><span>Coffe Name</span></h2>
            <a href="#">View more</a>
        </figcaption>           
    </figure>
```

and the CSS

```
    figure.imgbox figcaption {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 1em;
    height: 3.75em;
    background: #fff;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
    transition: transform 0.35s;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
}

figure.imgbox h2 {
    float: center;
}

figure.imgbox figcaption > span {
    float: center;
}

figure.imgbox p {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8em;
    padding: 2em;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: none;
    font-size: 90%;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s;
    transition: opacity 0.35s;
}

figure.imgbox h2,
figure.imgbox figcaption > span {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
    transition: transform 0.35s;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,200%,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,200%,0);
}

figure.imgbox figcaption > span::before {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    font-family: 'feathericons';
    speak: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.icon-eye::before {
    content: '\e000';
}

.icon-paper-clip::before {
    content: '\e001';
}

.icon-heart::before {
    content: '\e024';
}

figure.imgbox h2 {
    display: inline-block;
}

figure.imgbox:hover p {
    opacity: 1;
}

figure.imgbox:hover figcaption,
figure.imgbox:hover h2,
figure.imgbox:hover figcaption > span {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

figure.imgbox:hover h2 {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.05s;
    transition-delay: 0.05s;
}

figure.imgbox:hover figcaption > span:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

figure.imgbox:hover figcaption > span:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.15s;
    transition-delay: 0.15s;
}

figure.imgbox:hover figcaption > span:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
```

Maybe there is a problem with the grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its to do with the fact that when you apply the `box-shadow` to the `figure` element, the image then sits on top of it and obscures the `box-shadow`. Also, shadow can't be applied directly to an image as far as I am aware.

You could use a `:before` rule to get around this, or you could apply the image as a `background-image` to the `figure` and apply the `box-shadow` to this element as well.

The css for the `:before`, keeping your markup the same, would be thus:

```
.imgbox:before {
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    z-index: 2;
}
.imgbox img {
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this

```
<figure class="imgbox">
    <div class="ImgShadow"></div>
    <figcaption>
        <h2><span>Coffe Name</span></h2>
        <a href="#">View more</a>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

And CSS to ImgShadowclass :

```
.ImgShadow{
    background:url("http://i.imgur.com/DTL3hGL.jpg");  
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 10px #FF0000,inset -10px -10px 10px #FF0000;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mz5b7reh/)